# Would this be a reasonably secure website?

Tags: security, website, https, server, openbsd

If this is something for the Information Security Stack Exchange I understand. I want to know if this hypothetical setup is reasonably secure to the point where it can't be conventionally hacked remotely over Tor, from which it is accessible, and for it to be hacked the attacker would have to be using a 0 day or something. The server would be running on bare metal from my network, not on a VPS. Behind a router. Running the latest version of OpenBSD, OpenSSH, and httpd. OpenSSH would be restricted to only allowing local connections. httpd would be running under an OpenBSD VM, using the native `vmm` hypervisor built into the kernel. As said, httpd would route through Tor. OpenSSH would be running on the host machine, and I would manage the httpd VM by SSHing to the host and connecting using the native `vmctl` serial console. Both SSH and HTTP would be configured to run on abnormal port numbers in the thousands range to obscure it, and this would make it unlikely for the HTTP site to get indexed a by a crawler so only my friends who I notify of the address and port number would be able to view it. It would just serve static HTML pages and run for a few hours max when I feel like showing it to my friends. Is this reasonably secure?

Comment: "HTTP would be configured to run on abnormal port numbers in the thousands range to obscure it" - you don't want your HTTP server running on any internet-accessible port

Comment: @Steve What do you mean? It's not going to be able to access the internet without binding to a port. And it's technically not internet accessible or at least not in the typical way, sense it's connecting to Tor and is behind a router.

Comment: To run an onion service, you bind to a localhost port, not a port on a public interface. So it doesn't matter what port you use.